# Load R datasets in dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I am new with R and trying to use some of the datasets which exits within the R itself such as `AirPassengers`. I have looked at different code samples and in all of them usually data is loaded like:

```
data(AirPassengers)
```

However, I was wondering if it is possible to load this into a dataframe so then I can figure out the columns data types. I have tried `summary` but that only gives back dataset properties such as Mean, Min, etc. I also tried the following:

```
df <- data(AirPassengers)
```

Which is not working either.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load a dataset into R with data() using a variable instead of the dataset name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912833/load-a-dataset-into-r-with-data-using-a-variable-instead-of-the-dataset-name)

Comment: For the second, you need two lines: data(AirPassengers)
df <- AirPassengers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `data(AirPassengers)` adds a promise pointing to `AirPassengers` to your global environment. Once you use the `AirPassengers` object it will be loaded into your global environment. You can either just use the `AirPassengers` object like you would any object, or you can copy it to another variable, e.g.:

```
data(AirPassengers)
dat <- AirPassengers
```

If you run `class` on `AirPassengers` you will see that `AirPassengers` is not a data.frame. Try looking at the differences here:

```
class(AirPassengers)
# [1] "ts"
data(mtcars)
class(mtcars)
# [1] "data.frame"
summary(mtcars)
#     mpg             cyl             disp             hp       
# Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0  
# 1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5  
# Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0  
# Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7  
# 3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0  
# Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0  
# drat             wt             qsec             vs        
# Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513   Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000  
# 1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581   1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000  
# Median :3.695   Median :3.325   Median :17.71   Median :0.0000  
# Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217   Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375  
# 3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610   3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
# Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424   Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000  
# am              gear            carb      
# Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
# 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
# Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
# Mean   :0.4062   Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
# 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
# Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000
```

`AirPassengers` is a specific type of vector called a time-series. Look at `?ts` for more information.