# How to check whether a dataset exists in package?

Tags: r

Is there a more elegant (fail-safe/robust, shorter) way of checking whether a dataset (whose name is known as a character string) exists in a package than this?

```
rda.name <- "Animals" # name of the data set/.rda
rda.name %in% data(package = "MASS")[["results"]][,"Item"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I cannot replicate Sven's answer (under any recent version of R). The following works, but the usage of `suppressWarnings()` is rather ugly and the dataset is also loaded when calling `data()` this way (instead of *just* checking its existence). As such, I don't think this is preferable over my original version, but perhaps inspires someone to provide a fix.

```
exists(suppressWarnings(data(list = rda.name, package = "MASS")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach using `exists`:

```
exists(data("Animals", package = "MASS"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: `data` also has a verbose argument that will print out more information about available packages. For example, try `data("snack", verbose=TRUE)`.

Comment: I can't replicate the second part of Sven's answer. I obtain the warning `In data(rda.name, package = "MASS") : data set ‘rda.name’ not found`. This is why I specifically asked the question with a variable as name (and not the name itself as in the first part of this answer).

Comment: I now found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912833/load-a-dataset-into-r-with-data-using-a-variable-instead-of-the-dataset-name. The best answer seems to be the one which works with `data`'s `list` argument but then the data set is already loaded and not just checked for existence.

Comment: Also, if the dataset does *not* exist, a warning is thrown (catching that does not seem more elegant than what I did)

Comment: @MariusHofert Thanks for pointing out. The code with the variable indeed didn't work,